# Select more than non related entity in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to make basic statistics that get counts of data at tables or entities, and I am asking if I can do that at one query in Entity Framework ? I can do that in a SQL query by making more than select statement at stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach how to do it, in the end you still should construct SQL Select statment, but still.

First, you should add namespases:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
```

And then you can use this code to get all tables with row count.

```
YourDBEntities ent = new YourDBEntities();
ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ent).ObjectContext;
MetadataWorkspace metadataWorkspace = context.MetadataWorkspace;
EntityContainer container = metadataWorkspace
    .GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace).First();
ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EntitySetBase> entitySetBase = container.BaseEntitySets;

//Get Table Names
var tableNames = entitySetBase
    .Where(x => x.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntitySet) //Get Tables Only
    .Select(x => x.Name);

//Get data
foreach (var tableName in tableNames)
{
    //Counstruct query for each table
    var selectSQL = String.Format(@"SELECT '{1}', COUNT(1) AS Count  
                                    FROM {0}", tableName, tableName);
    ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord> query = context.CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(selectSQL);
    ObjectResult<DbDataRecord> results = query.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
    DbDataRecord res =  results.First();
    //Write to console
    Console.WriteLine("Table '{0}' contains {1} of rows", res[0], res[1]);
}
```